# Docusign API - Umlaut character in Recepient name

Tags: docusignapi

The recipient name has an umlaut character -> "François"

While sending the envelope to this recipient using the Docusign Rest API v2, I'm getting an error in response with

Error Code -> UNSPECIFIED_ERROR

Error Message -> An item with the same key has already been added.

If I change the recipient's name to a string with no umlaut characters, the envelope works.

Is there any way to fix this at an account level or while sending the request to Docusign?

Following is the request xml which works without the umlaut character **ç** in the recipient's name.

```
<envelopeDefinition><emailSubject>Agreement Name</emailSubject> 
<status>sent</status><documents><document><name>Agreement Name</name>
<documentId>368649304</documentId><documentBase64>Document 
Contents</documentBase64></document></documents><recipients><signers>
<signer><recipientId>1</recipientId><email>TestEmail</email>
<name>François Harnandez</name>
<routingOrder>1</routingOrder><tabs><signHereTabs><signHere>
<anchorString>ICLM_ExtSignature:1</anchorString></signHere></signHereTabs>
<dateSignedTabs><dateSigned><anchorString>ExtDate1</anchorString>/dateSigned>
</dateSignedTabs></tabs></signer></signers></recipients>
</envelopeDefinition>
```

Comment: That is not an umlaut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested this to see what I actually passed to the CURL request and here's what I get (json instead of xml) when I pass in `Tèst User` as a recipientName

### Request

```
POST: https://{server}/restapi/v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/
{
    "emailSubject": "Testing",
    "templateId": "{templateId}",
    "status": "sent",
    "templateRoles": [
        {
            "email": "email@domain.com",
            "name": null,
            "roleName": "Role 1",
            "clientUserId": 12345654321
        }
    ]
}
```

### Response

```
{
  "errorCode": "INVALID_USERNAME_FOR_RECIPIENT",
  "message": "The user name for the recipient is invalid. The user name is invalid for recipient email email@domain.com"
}
```

I would expect this error message to come back if I'm passing in a null value, is your XML encoding stripping out that value? Can you see what you're actually passing to DocuSign with an entire response?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this request in JSON instead of XML ?
I have try in JSON with name "François" and I have no problem to send the request and to sign with this name : https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtWUc.png